# Unable to create list of model instances (Experiences)

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-serializer

I am trying to create multiple instances i.e experience for the same user but unable to do. Instead I have to hit the url twice in order to add multiple data.

**serialzers.py**

```
class WorkExperienceSerialzer(BaseModelSerializer):

hidden_fields_to_add = {"created_by": None, "user": None}

    class Meta(BaseModelSerializer.Meta):
        model = WorkExperienceData
        fields = [
            "company",
            "designation",
            "description",
            "from_date",
            "to_date",
            "reference_name",
            "reference_mailid",
            "user",
            "id",
            ]
        extra_kwargs = {
            "user": {"read_only": True},
        }

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        many = kwargs.pop('many', True)
        super(WorkExperienceSerialzer, self).__init__(many=many, *args, **kwargs)

    def create(self, validated_data, **kwargs):
            instance = super(WorkExperienceSerialzer, self).create(validated_data)
            return instance

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        instance = super(WorkExperienceSerialzer, self).update(
            instance, validated_data
            )
        return instance

    def get_default_value_for_field(self, field):

        value = super(WorkExperienceSerialzer, self).get_default_value_for_field(
            field
        )

        if not value:
            if field == "user":
                value = self.context["request"].user

        return value
```

**views.py**

```
class WorkExperienceViewSet(ViewListUpdateDeleteViewSet, BaseModelViewSet):
    queryset = WorkExperienceData.objects.all()
    serializer_class = WorkExperienceSerialzer

    def get_serializer(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if "data" in kwargs:
            data = kwargs["data"]

        # check if many is required
        if isinstance(data, list):
            kwargs["many"] = True

    return super(WorkExperienceViewSet, self).get_serializer(*args, **kwargs)
```

But when I am trying to pass data like below

```
         [
    {
        "company": "something",
        "designation": "something",
        "description": "something",
        "from_date": "2020-10-15",
        "to_date": "2020-11-14",
        "reference_name": "something",
        "reference_mailid": "something@gmail.com"
    },
    {
        "company": "nothing",
        "designation": "nothing",
        "description": "nothing",
        "from_date": "2020-10-25",
        "to_date": "2020-10-27",
        "reference_name": "nothing",
        "reference_mailid": "nothing@gmail.com"
    }
]
```

I am getting something like this

*'ListSerializer' object is not iterable*

I tried to change views by adding many=True but then also its not working

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON has two trailing commas which are not allowed in JSON (but allowed in Python)

Try this:

```json
[
    {
        "company": "something",
        "designation": "something",
        "description": "something",
        "from_date": "2020-10-15",
        "to_date": "2020-11-14",
        "reference_name": "something",
        "reference_mailid": "something@gmail.com"
    },
    {
        "company": "nothing",
        "designation": "nothing",
        "description": "nothing",
        "from_date": "2020-10-25",
        "to_date": "2020-10-27",
        "reference_name": "nothing",
        "reference_mailid": "nothing@gmail.com"
    }
]
```